# Permissions to attach client auth certificate in Windows

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

I have Win32 app that does web service calls that need a client auth cert to be attached to each message. The code works fine on all the machines I manage, but some clients are getting issues where the cert is failing to be attached. In the past these issues have usually been permissions related, but in this case I'm not able to see any obvious permissions issues. The app does have sufficient permissions to install the cert into the Windows cert store (CurrentUser\MY) but for whatever reason is unable to then pull the cert out. Are there specific granular rights that need to be set to allow the cert to be accessed properly?

Answer (score 0):

Are the users on their own computers (out of Domain Network) or attached to a Domain Network?

If you have users in other networks or not in your domain network those users may have Group Policy definitions preventing your app from installing said certificate into their store.

Comment: They are on their own PCs, the issues have been with both computers on a Domain Network and not. In the majority of the reports I've seen, the users have been able to use MMC and verify my application can install the cert into the cert store, but it's not able to then attach the cert to the message later on. That's why I'm looking for specific group policy definitions that might be causing that.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes, it's self signed through my company's own PKI system.

Comment: I suspect its a certificate trust issue, but you mentioned that some are within your own network, which wouldn't make any sense for their pc not to trust the cert. However if they have their own software on the system, maybe their hosts files were altered and perhaps have your cert server blocked. Could be outdated system without the root certificate in it, or even a system with a changed date, making the certificate invalid? It seems like it could be a LOT of different things.

Comment: Well enough systems inside my company and outside my company work with no problems, so I think in general the cert is good enough for Windows to attach to my program's messages. However for some small percentage of the install base, it's not working. Currently I'm looking into the possibility there are virtualized Cert stores in newer versions of Windows such that there are really two CurrentUser\My locations and that sometimes my program is getting confused which to look at.

Comment: That seems plausible.